# Certifications for statisticians

Tags: marketing, portfolio, foreign-markets

I would like to learn more about the certifications in the domain of statistics. I am mostly interested in those existing in France and European Union, but experience from elsewhere could be also interesting - it could give me useful keywords or ideas. If it needs to be narrowed down, medical and biostatistics are probably of the more immediate interest.

**Background:**
I have strongly quantitative background (due to my studies and later work experience.) Most of the projects that I have worked on in the last few years - either as a freelancer or as an employee - dealt with mathematical modeling and implementation of these models in python. I stress that they had to do not so much with my specific domain knowledge (physics and computational biology), as with the ability to write and solve equations, decent knowledge of probability theory, and python coding skills.

With all this, I still have difficulty positioning myself on the freelance/job market - I can claim to be neither a statistician, nor a developer, nor a machine learning person - since anyone with an undergraduate degree in these fields easily beats me on some routine task that they were trained to do. Neither do I aspire to compete for the basic level projects in either field.

Nevertheless, I think that I could benefit from confirming my credentials. Notably in everything concerning statistics. Perhaps this could even open access to projects/jobs where formal certifications are required (e.g., in big companies or government run sectors.)

Comment: What did google show you? What are your search terms?

Comment: @MS-SPO I am not asking about pulling stuff from Google - this I can do myself. Do you have some relevant expertise or is this just an attempt at bullying? (No offense - I see that English is not your firsts language, so your comment might be rude unintentionally.)

Comment: No bullying, it's an attempt to clarify your question, like we do on https://tex.stackexchange.com/. More often than not new users there leave out important details. // And yes, a question like yours should yield plenty of institutions you look for via a search engine. If so, I wonder what may be missing. So I still think your question is incomplete.

Comment: @MS-SPO I am not new to stackexchange - only not very active in this community. My question is not about the institutions where one may get education, but about the government certification. E.g., anyone who knows languages can be a translator, but only the translations by certified translators could be accepted by government: in courts, for visa applications, etc. A closer example - quality experts have to be certified to work for certain industries - like avionics, nuclear, etc.

Comment: Please review your question and add information to it, which might be missing. Having to „wade“ through a long series of comments isn’t welcome by many. Bye

Comment: If you want a fancy name for get RRHH/Clients atención maybe data analyst or data scientist but I need to know more about your skills

Comment: @rubengavidia0x thanks for the comment. Could you be more specific about the skills that you are asking about - like giving a few examples? Does the background as described in the question sounds too generic (I appreciate the opinion on that.)